# Weird change in theme

Tags: desktop-environments, headphones

I've had something really weird happen to my 12.04. I was installing new desktop environments, and now I have no sound through my headphones and the "pop up" theme has changed. by pop up, I mean the icons that appear when I use hot keys to do things like change volume, brightness, etc.

I first noticed this change after I left my computer on, but was away from it. I hadn't logged out of my session, but the theme changed when I woke back up from suspend. The only other thing I had done was the regular update stuff with update manager.

So, the question is how do I go back to how it was this morning? At the very least, I can deal with the icons being different, but I need sound out my headphone jack! here's a pic

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByuTthf4CDVhVE1XdF9nTEhRalk/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!!!

Comment: What desktop environments did you install?

Comment: XFCE, Awesome, and I already had Cinnamon. I've since purged them.

Comment: Okay, that's a start.  Could you post a screenshot of the notifications?  That would help a lot.

Comment: I'm really sorry for being such a n00b, but where do I find the current notifications. I'm just using the standard unity DE

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the "pop-ups".  They are called "notifications" :)

Comment: I'm still not sure where to go for a listing of my recent notifications... but I did find this image with an example of what I want to go back to. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=5dv7kj&s=7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem! I uninstalled all XFCE stuff using the terminal command found at this page: [Remove XFCE](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-11-10-how-to-completely-uninstall-remove-xfce). It completely fixed the problem! Headphone is back, and the theme went back to normal!

Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Yeah, this was a problem with new desktop environments overwriting the default applications for things with their own custom applications.  I'm glad you fixed it :)